# Business Logic Classes Naming

Tags: c#, business-logic, business-objects, business-logic-layer

I have a business layer that has some business objects/POCOs/entities/whatever. I also have some repositories for the data access. Up until this point, I've been accessing the repositories directly from my UI layer. I'm at a point where I actually need some more classes that aren't straight CRUD, so I'm going to create some business logic classes that will do the logic, and CRUD, and the repositories won't be accessed by the UI anymore (which should probably have been done from the start).

What should I call these classes? The only thing I can think of are service classes, but I have actual WCF services in this application, so that will make it confusing. The WCF services will also be using these classes, so having a service use a service class seems odd and confusing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I use the "Service" naming convention as well. It's true the "service" has become a very overloaded term in the industry, but it makes the most sense. Developers reviewing the code should be able to determine the difference between a Application/Domain Service vs a WCF service, and while having a WCF service call other service classes may seem confusing, I think you'll find that it isn't. The idea of a service is that it is code that performs a function, and is available for use by other code. It might be an internal service, or it might be a service externally exposed via http or whatever. But the idea of what the code does is the same.

Answer (score 5):

If your 'services' are orchestrating business logic using a number of domain objects, you're likely implementing the [Facade Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/patterns/patternfacade.aspx) - so perhaps you can name them with this suffix, eg `OrderManagementFacade`

Comment: This pattern is new to me, but I like it. It's very descriptive unlike "service".

Comment: It is descriptive except when there are no domain objects and these "services" perform the logic themselves.

Answer (score 4):

From your description, it sounds like the WCF classes are actually implementing a service *host*.  I typically name such classes with a "ServiceHost" suffix.  It separates them nicely from the actual service classes.

So, for example, you would have your business logic in a class named "CustomerService" and the corresponding WCF class would be named "CustomerServiceHost".